# Unable to Dragend Navigator handles in HighStock

Tags: highcharts

I am using a 'spline' chart type in HighStock. The problem is that when I start using either side handles on the Navigator, I'm not able to stop dragging and the handles get stuck with the mouse cursor. I've tried replicating the issue on JSFiddle but it works fine there. Since it's proprietary data I'm playing with, I cannot really post any code. But I do hope that I have made my question pretty clear. If there's anything else I can add, do let me know.

Comment: For sure you have errors in console. Since it works properly in jsFiddle, it's probably caused by old version of Highstock, try to update to 3.0.6 version. If this won't help, post at least Highstock options - without data.

Comment: Thank you for your response @PawełFus . There was indeed no error in console. I found my fix and going to update the question right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that MouseUp DOM event was not firing. I got to know this when I used `setExtremes` event for xAxis. Then, I looked around and found that I had a `$('html').on('mouseup')` somewhere in another js file messing it all up.

Removed the mouseup event written on html and voila, it worked :)

Thanks to everyone who gave a thought to this.

Cheers!